# Intellij IDEA: Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, java, intellij

I installed Intellij IDEA from on my arch using `yay`. I worked fine but recently it started doing this:

```bsh
john@arch-thinkpad ~ [1]> intellij-idea-ultimate-edition
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I fix this problem so I can run intellij IDEA normaly like in good old times ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch to java-11. Intellij calls the vm with an option that is no longer supported by java 15.

If you start Intellij via terminal (and java 11) it shows you that message:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

For now this workaround works. Remember to change the Java version in arch with archlinux-java.

Install java 11:

```
$sudo pacman -S jdk11-openjdk
```

Switch to java 11:

```
$sudo archlinux-java set java-11-openjdk
```

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

[Uzumaki D. Ichigo's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640245/422391) does not involves changing the JDK.

However the "idea.vmoptions" file in the /bin directory is overwritten when idea runs.
JVM options must be changed in the file with the same name, but in the configuration directory as JetBrains documentation states.
This can be done following the instructions in the official documentation for [idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory) and [clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory):

> Configuration directory
>
> Syntax ~/.config/JetBrains/
>
> Example
> ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3

It is not needed to cut the line.
It can be just commented out:

```
#-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can remove that option and use it with the latest JDK.

In `/opt/clion/bin/clion64.vmoptions`, comment out / delete the following line

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also point your IDE to the correct Java Boot Runtime it needs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under
…and keep your system's java up-to-date.